# Заполнение полей

Tags: php, форма

Можно ли используя php, зайти на сайт и заполнить там форму, дождаться результатов и передать данные назад?

Был бы очень рад ссылке на русскоязычный мануал.

Comment: Например сделать запрос на сайт с помощью cURL'a и получить данные. прим: [Авторизация в вконтакте][1] 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/241725/php-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если обработчик формы (чужой) не проверяет отправителя, то можно.
Используя метод POST

```
$data = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3";
curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/form_action.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$res = curl_exec($curl);
if($res){
    $response = json_decode($res);
//или $response = uri_decode($res);

}
```

Используя метод GET

```
$Url = "http://example.com/form_action.php?key1=value1&key2=value2";                
$response = file_get_contents($Url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно через *file_get_contents*.

Answer (score -2):

`file_get_contents` умеет и `POST` запросы делать.